# Cloned Suse machine wont boot

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, opensuse

I am very much still a linux noob. I am cloning a current Suse workstation, attempting to create another identical workstation.

I have attempted booting the new workstation with the hard drive in a machine with newer hardware - I have also now tried booting up the hard drive in a machine with the same hardware as the source.

Here's where my knowledge of linux is lacking. The menu comes to up select Suse, I select it - it seems to begin to boot, but I get the following messages:

```
fb: conflicting fb hw usage inteldrmfb vs VESA VGA - removing gen
Trying manual resume from /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST380815AS_9RW0BDRC-part2
Resume device " not found (ignoring)
```

I assume this is referencing a partition on the hard drive. I've lost my way here, trying all different kinds of ways to restore this machine. Can anyone help me understand what the issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this post helped correct the issue: [Unable to use cloned VM, OpenSUSE, VirtualBox](https://superuser.com/questions/432358/unable-to-use-cloned-vm-opensuse-virtualbox)

The system was booting looking for a drive that didn't exist - once changing the name it is booting.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).